How can I join the head of my mesh to the rigify armature?
there is something I can't figure out how to solve: the head doesn't move with the armature. I tried this: I select the head in Object Mode then I go in Edit Mode to select all of the head mesh and go back in Object Mode and ⇧ Shift select the armature and then I Ctrl + P to automatic weight in Pose Mode.
Everything seems ok (no error message) but the head does not move with the armature.

I don't know why it is not parented when everything else is. Can someone please enlighten me?

Selecting all in Edit mode is unnecessary, and don't go to pose mode, because in this case only selected bones will be weighted.
So, in Object mode, select the head mesh, Shift select the Armature, press Ctrl P > with Automatic Weights.

Thank you @Josh but it does not change anything..It is the same thing when all the mesh except the head mesh is hidden. Any other idea?

I tried with  Envelope Weights and it moved the head... but the armature is not workable, it takes me at least 20 seconds to move any part of the mesh, zut!

I finally found what was going wrong: my head mesh was too dense, it had too many faces. When I un-subdivided the head mesh, it parented to the armature with ctrl+p>deform with Automatic Weights.
